# Creating a definition that takes undefined number of parameters

Tags: python, pandas, definition

What would be the best method of turning a code like below to be able to accept as many dataframes as we would like?

```
def q_grab(df, df2, df3, q): #accepts three dataframes and a column name. Looks up column in all dataframes and combine to one
    data = df[q], df2[q], df3[q]
    headers = [q+"_1", q+"_2", q+"_3"]
    data2 = pd.concat(data, axis = 1, keys=headers)
    return data2

q = 'covid_condition'
data2 = q_grab(df, df2, df3, q) #If I run function pid_set first, it will create new df based on pID it looks like
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One approach is to use * operator to get a list of arguments
(but name your final argument, so it isn't part of the list):

Something like this:

```
def q_grab(*dfs, q=None): # q is a named argument to signal end of positional arguments
    data = [df[q] for df in dfs]
    headers = [q+"_"+str(i) for i in range(len(dfs))]
    data2 = pd.concat(data, axis = 1, keys=headers)
    return data2

q = 'covid_condition'
data2 = q_grab(df, df2, df3, q=q)
```

A probably cleaner alternative, is to go ahead and pass a list of dataframes as the first argument:

```
 def q_grab(dfs,q):
```

called with:

```
 data2 = q.grab([df,df2,df3], q)
```

using the function code as above

Comment: Thank you Rufus. That's a great solution. I forgot that list comprehensions will automatically place a comma between the elements

Comment: Also, I have read that *args should always be placed at the end of the parameters. Any reason as to why it is first? How come q= None rather than leaving it as q?

Comment: *args has to be after the unnamed (positional) arguments, but before named arguments.  So you could have changed your argument list to  `def q_grab(q,*dfs)` and not need to name the column argument, just put it before the variable length list.

Comment: I noticed a small error.  When generating your headers, you want `str(i+1)`, not `str(i)` to give the same numbering as your original code.